# How to Store timezone with timestamp in xapi?

Tags: xapi

I am  currently  exploring Learning locker which is a LRS and store XAPI statements .I see the timestamp in XAPI should follow  ISO 8601 format .I see it can be represented as  `"2015-01-01T01:00Z"` but how can I store the timezone information too like  `"2007-04-05T12:30−02:00"`.XAPI documentation suggests setting the timeozone but there is no clear way how we can do it .
Any clue on this will be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Generally the `Z` indicates a timezone, specifically the UTC timezone. It is preferred that all statement timestamps are stored using UTC and then if they need to be handled relative to a local timezone then that conversion happens at the point of need rather than via the stored data. If you must store it with the specific timezone then the format you showed with the `-02:00` should work. NOTE: In the proposed (nearly accepted) version 2.x of the xAPI specification all timestamps will have to be recorded in UTC, see:

> A Timestamp shall be formatted to UTC

(https://gitlab.com/IEEE-SA/xapi/9274.1.1/xapi-base-standard-documentation/-/blob/master/9274.1.1%20xAPI%20Base%20Standard%20for%20Content.md#527-additional-requirements-for-data-types)

So it would likely be better to go ahead and start following that pattern.

If the timezone is relevant for other purposes it would be better to track the timezone itself separately from the timestamp (likely as a `result` or `context` extension).